# How do I suspend Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, suspend

What command suspends an appropriately configured Arch Linux system?

User story: It's now or never. I'm on the run. I don't have time to read [ArchWiki/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate) but I want to be energy-efficient. How do I suspend Arch Linux before I miss my appointment?

Note: This question exists because Arch Wiki isn't straightforward the way StackExchange is and because it's a command (or a list of commands?) that is rarely used, making it hard to remember.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What command suspends an appropriately configured Arch Linux system?

```
systemctl suspend
```

You might have to use `sudo`. There might be other ways, depending on the configuration. If anybody is willing to extend or re-answer with a complete list of what kind of one-liner commands achieve this commonly on Arch Linux systems, that'd be great to all other energy-economic people on the run for that important meeting.

Answer (score 15):

If you look under the section *System Commands* in the `man`-page for `systemctl`, you'll see the various options that are system related.

A brief list is as follows for different *modes*:

- `# systemctl default`
- `# systemctl rescue`
- `# systemctl emergency`

Then, suspensions and the likes of which:

- `# systemctl halt`
- `# systemctl poweroff`
- `# systemctl reboot`
- `# systemctl suspend`
- `# systemctl hibernate`
- `# systemctl hybrid-sleep`

For more information regarding the system commands, you're [recommended to read the `man`-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F2</kbd> first, to find a text terminal, to improve the preparation done, then:

```
echo mem | sudo tee /sys/power/state
```

Or...

```
sudo su
echo mem > /sys/power/state
```

This will work on any Linux that supports it, whether it has `systemctl` or not. Of course, your distributions' official way is best. But this is a good go-to if you're on the run.